# Class does not exist - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_controllers.htm). I am currently using laravel 5.3 so it is a little outdated. I have done step by step as said by the tutorial, however, I get

```
   ReflectionException in Container.php line 749:
   Class First does not exist

in Container.php line 749
at ReflectionClass->__construct('First') in Container.php line 749
at Container->build('First', array()) in Container.php line 644
at Container->make('First', array()) in Application.php line 709
at Application->make('First') in Kernel.php line 173
at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in index.php line 58
at require_once('C:\xampp5\htdocs\laravel\laravel\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Everything is just like in the tutorial. I have no idea where could be the problem.

Comment: Add your code please!

Comment: @rbr94 I said the code is exactly like the tutorial. Like literally a copypaste.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you created a `FirstMiddleware` but you referred to it only as `First` here:

```
<?php
Route::get('/usercontroller/path',[
   'middleware' => 'First',
   'uses' => 'UserController@showPath'
]);
```

As stated in the official docs,

> if you would like to assign middleware to specific routes, you should
>   first assign the middleware a key in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`

So, add this to your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // the other route middlewares are defined here
    'First' => \App\Http\Middleware\FirstMiddleware::class, // add this line
]
```

I think this should be enough.